# List all Jenkins Jobs including subfolders with count and list all enabled and disabled jenkins including subfolders with count using groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

In Jenkins, I want to list all Jenkins jobs using the groovy script, I have tried a couple of groovy scripts to get the jobs, and it's working fine, Now I want to get the count of all Jobs without folders and subfolders.
Below is the groovy script which I have tried to the all jobs list including folder and subfolders, but I need only jobs which are WorkflowJob, FreestyleProject, and maven build

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each{
    println it.name + " - " + it.class
}
```

and 2 one is how can I get a list of active jobs and disabled jobs list and count
I have tried from below reference, but it's not working

[find disabled job link found in google](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/listdisabledjobs.groovy)

Someone please can help on this, help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 01**

I'm not sure what you meant by a Maven build Job. But, here is how to list all the Jobs which are either a Workflow Job or a Freestyle Job and which do not reside in a folder/subfolder.

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { jobitem ->
      
  if(jobitem.getName() == jobitem.getFullName()) { // This means it's not in a folder
    if(jobitem instanceof org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob || jobitem instanceof hudson.model.FreeStyleProject) {
        println("Job Name: " + jobitem.getFullName())
    }
  }  
}
```

**Part 02**

List disabled Jobs.

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { jobitem ->     
  if(jobitem.isDisabled()) {
        println("Job Name: " + jobitem.getFullName())
  }  
}
```

List Jobs that are not disabled/active.

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { jobitem ->     
  if(!jobitem.isDisabled()) {
        println("Job Name: " + jobitem.getFullName())
  }  
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help, I need jobs that reside in folders and views also and the total count.
and also see that for Part 02 you have given same code, can you please check it once

Comment: @KNCK the part02 is correct, if you take a closer look at the condition, the condition is negated(!). Regarding the Jobs in Views, since it was not mentioned in the original question please feel free to create a new SO ticket for that.

Comment: A job can only exist in one physical location: folder[/folder]/job. But it might appear in many views.

Comment: how to get all enabled jobs using a groovy script, I have tried multiple ways, but no use, can anyone please give some script to only enabled jobs list

Comment: @KNCK Isn't the above script working for you?

Comment: @ycr "List Jobs that are not disabled/active." I'm getting full list of jobs instead of only active pipelines

Comment: @ycr
Can you please let me know how to get active jenkins pipelines and exclude all multibranch jobs/branches

Comment: @KNCK Please feel free to create new questions for new requirements.